# Azure App Service for windows: Azure DevOps Release does not unzip the file on wwwroot forder

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-devops, next.js, azure-appservice

I have built an app using **[NextJS](https://nextjs.org/)**

I would like to deploy the app on an **[Azure App service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/)**

the deployment WORKS on the [Vercel server](https://fmplatform-nextjs.vercel.app/) without any customization

I am using the DevOps tools: Pipelines and Release features

**the issue**

The deployment on the "Azure App Service" fails because:

The zip file containing the deployed version of the app **IS NOT** unzipped under the site/wwwroot directory

**QUESTION**: which is the missing task that will deploy the zip file into the wwwroot directory?

here is the zip file uploaded by the Release' job

[image: zip file containing the deployed app on /data/SitePackages]

**here is the Pipeline description**

[image: DevOps pipeline]

**here is the Release description**

[image: Azure App Service Deploy: fmplatform-nextjs-win]

Comment: The same way you have the `Archive files` in your pipeline, there's also `Extract files`

Answer (score 0):

It seems the ZIP is being deployed in "[run from package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-run-package)" mode. This should usually not be a problem. It is probably not running because something else removes the AppSetting `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE`, or because the app needs write access to the file system.

You can either unzip the artifact before deploying with `Extract Files`, or try to force a different deployment method by tinkering with either the [App Service Deploy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app-deployment?view=azure-devops#auto-detect-logic) or the [Azure Web App task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app-deployment?view=azure-devops#auto-detect-logic).